# Select +- 2 minutes with the time-format()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select not the exactly arrivaltime from my arrivaltimes table but -+ 2 minutes with this query:

```
SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops
 ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id 
WHERE weekday =  ?
and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
and name LIKE ?
```

How can I select +- 2 minutes?

Comment: What is the type of the arrivaltime field? `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` or other?

Comment: @Tom: `arrivaltime time NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field arrivaltime is a `TIME` field, this should work:

```
SELECT route
FROM arrivaltimes
INNER JOIN stops ON (arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id)
WHERE
    weekday =  ?
    AND arrivaltime >= curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    AND arrivaltime <= curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    AND name LIKE ?
```

Or you can use the [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
SELECT route
FROM arrivaltimes
INNER JOIN stops ON (arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id) 
WHERE
    weekday =  ?
    AND arrivaltime BETWEEN curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    AND name LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`BETWEEN....AND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) and [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp):

```
SELECT route 
from arrivaltimes 
INNER JOIN stops ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id 
WHERE weekday =  ?
and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i') BETWEEN 
    time_format(DATE_ADD(curtime,INTERVAL -2 MINUTE) ,'%H:%i') AND 
    time_format(DATE_ADD(curtime,INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) ,'%H:%i')
and name LIKE ?
```